# How can I backfill a Java string array based on two other arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have two arrays:

```
String[] ArrayA = {"9","1","4","2","3"}; 
String[] ArrayB = {"9","2","8"};
```

How do I get a new array like the following

```
String[] ArrayC = {"9","2","8","A","A"};
```

The logic is to create a new `ArrayC` of length equal to `ArrayA` and backfill the remaining array elements (`ArrayA` length minus `ArrayB` length = 2) difference with `"A"`.

Comment: You'll need to know how to create arrays and write loops. That's all we can help with, without knowing what you've already tried.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 6):

Read the javadoc of [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

```
arrayC = Arrays.copyOf(arrayB, arrayA.length);
Arrays.fill(arrayC, arrayB.length, arrayA.length, "A");
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you care to explain? This looks like a perfectly fine answer to me.

Comment: I can understand the down-vote: no explanation. Though intentionally just a javadoc link. Reasons: (1) no own effort in question (2) just might be some homework.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over `arrayB` and copy it:

```
String[] arrayA = {"9","1","4","2","3"}; 
String[] arrayB = {"9","2","8"};
String[] arrayC = new String[arrayA.length];

// copy arrayB:
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; ++i) {
    arrayC[i] = arrayB[i];
} 

// fill in the remainder:
for (int i = arrayB.length; i < arrayA.length; ++i) {
    arrayC[i] = "A";
}
```

Comment: Why not rely on API functions for this kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous posted code,this is a generic method which satisfy your need, it takes 3 params , two arrays and the word to be used to be used in replacing empty elements

```
public static String [] fill(String [] arrayA, String[] arrayB ,String word) {
String[] toBeCopied = null ;
   int size ;
if( arrayA.length > arrayB.length ) {
    size = arrayA.length ;
    toBeCopied = arrayB ;
} else {
    size = arrayB.length ;
    toBeCopied = arrayA ;
}
String[] arrayC = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < toBeCopied.length; ++i) {
    arrayC[i] = toBeCopied[i];
}
for (int i=toBeCopied.length;i<arrayC.length ;i++ )
    arrayC[i] = word;
   return arrayC ;
```

}